# Which is the best way to handle big CSV files (Java, MySQL, MongoDB)

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb, csv

i need to handle a **big CSV file** with around **+750.000 rows of data**. Each line has around **1000+ characters** and ~50 **columns**, and i am really not sure what's the **best** (or atleast good and sufficient) **way to handle and manipulate** this kind of data.

I need to do the following steps:

1. **Compare the values of two Colomns** and **write the result to a new column** (this one seems easy)
2. **Compare values of two lines** and do stuff. (e.g delete if one value is duplicated.)
3. **Compare values of two different files**.

My Problem is that this is currently done with PHP and/ or Excel and the limits are **nearly exceeded** + this takes a long time to process and will be **no longer possible** when the files get even bigger.

I have **3** different possibilities in mind:

1. **Use MySQL**, create a table (or two) and do the comparing, adding or deleting part. (I am not really familiar with SQL and would have to learn it, also it should be done automatically so there is the **problem** that you **cant create tables of CSV files** )
2. **Use Java** creating **Objects in ArrayList or Linked Lists** and to "the stuff" (to **operations would be easy but handling that much data will probably be the problem**)
   (Is it even **possible to save that many files in Java** or does it crash / is there a **good tool etc.**?)
3. **Use Clojure along with MongoDB** to  add files from CSV to MongoDB and read files using Mongo.

(Name additional possibilities if you have another idea ..)

All in all I am not a Pro in any of these but would like to solve this problem / get some hints or even your opinion.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: You should say what means *Compare values of two lines* and *Compare values of two different files*. If you just need to compare an *identifier* (possibly made from more than one field), a unique index over a database table could help.

Comment: it might help if you show a part of your cvs file then we know what you talking about.

Comment: Sorry for the imprecise explanation. The file comes with values like a ID for certain products, if these IDs are duplicates, one of them has to be removed. Another case would be compairing to columns (e.g. old and new price) if they differ in value. I hope that made it clearer.

Comment: Don't do it in Java, save yourself the hassle of writing a ton of code.

Comment: Postgres is the easiest solution, plus it will help you forever to know how to use it so you should learn now.

Answer (score 1):

Since in our company we work a lot with huge csv files here are some ideas:

- because these files are in our case always exported from some other relational database we always use PostgreSQL, MySQL or golang + SQLite to be able to use simple plain SQL queries which are in these cases most simple and reliable solution
- number of rows you describe is quite low from the point of view of all these databases so do not worry
- all have native internal solution for import / export of CSV - which works much quicker than anything created manually
- for repeated standard checks I use golang + SQLite with `:memory:` database - this is definitely the quickest solution
- MySQL is definitely very good and quick for checks you described but choose of database depends also on how sophisticated analysis you would need to do further - for example MySQL up to 5.7 still does not have window functions which you could need later - so consider using PostgreSQL in some cases too...

Comment: "for example MySQL up to 5.7 still does not have window functions which you could need later" Good news MySQL 8.0 is in development which do support window functions.

Comment: So far, i had troubles importing CSV files (even smaller) with the Import Tool from MySQL-Workbench, because it couldnt read some characters apart from ASCII.  The question is, does PostgeSQL has that kind of Tool. This is a process that has to be done with different/ new CSV files at least once a week, so can a table be created automiaticly by PostgreSQL?

Comment: But how do you import the **CSV file into a new table with the respective cloumns?** I searched multiple days without finding a solution for it, either **its limited to a certain size**, or its cancled due to a **wrong encoding** error-

Answer (score 0):

I normally use [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org) for this kind of tasks. PostgreSQL [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html) allows importing CSV data easily. Then you get a table with your CSV data and the power for SQL (and a reasonable database) to do basically anything you want with the data.

I am pretty sure MySQL have similar capabilities of importing CSV, I just generally prefer PostgreSQL.

I would not use Java for CSV processing. This will be too much code and unless you take care of indices, the processing will not be performant. An SQL database is much better equiped for tabular data processing (should not be a surprize).

I wouldn't use MongoDB, my impression is that it is less powerful in update operations compared to an SQL database. But this is just an opinion, take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: So far i have used MySQL Workbench, which usually provides a tool that creates tables from a csv file. But the encoding isnt accepted in that Import tool. But asides from that, wouldnt you recommend using Java (or Clojure) at all? I'll take a look at postgreSQL, thank you

Comment: Hey, sorry for asking again, but is it possible to create a **new table based on the first line of that CSV file** in PostgreSQL? So far i have read, that it is needed to create a table beforehand.

Comment: @NICK_WANTED As far as I see from the syntax of the `COPY` command, `table_name` is needed beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Python with the pandas package. On a machine with enough memory (say 16GB) it should be able to handle your CSV files with ease. The main thing is - anyone with some experience with pandas will be able to develop a quick script for you and tell you in a few minutes if your job is doable or not. To get you started:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

You might need to specify the column type if you get into memory issues.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use Spark. Even in a standalone machine the performance is incredible. You can use Scala and Python to handle your data. It's flexible and you can do processing that is impossible in Java or relational database. 
The other choices are great also, but I'd consider Spark to all analytics needs from now on.

Comment: Spark is a great tool, but the catch is it simply ignores keys with null values.yet this is great feature but it should be configurable.